# Проблема с mySQL-PHP-JSON UTF-8

Tags: php, mysql, json, кодировка, utf

При настройке удаленного сервера, столкнулся с проблемой, когда при выводе JSON данных, все символы юникода заменяются на `?`. В консоли/MySQLWorkBench'e все выводится корректно, сама страница отображает все остальные юникод символы нормально, но через JSON приходят только `?`.
Пробовал:

```
//php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$sql->set_charset("utf8");

//mysql 
SET NAMES utf8
```

UPD: Прямой вывод из базы также дает запись вида `????`
UPD2: Кодировки для каждого типа:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: А без JSON все работает?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev с базы все выводится через `JSON`, прямой вывод не тестил, но попробую. Вся остальная страница выводится корректно. Сами записи в бд хранятся корректно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением в файл `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` `[mysqld]` директив

```
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

*И не забудьте перезагрузить `mysql` :)*

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема при выводе JSON в QML, решилась добавлением этих двух строк:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$sql->set_charset("utf8");
```

Где $sql - объект mysqli.

Comment: Увы, все это уже использовано, никакого эффекта